# Alinhar colunas dentro da listbox (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

Estou usando esse turorial para iniciar um projeto:
[tutorial sqlite](http://raccoon.ninja/pt/dev-pt/tutorial-aplicacao-em-python-sqlite-parte-01/)

Gostaria de alinhar as colunas dentro da `listbox`, já tentei de algumas formas sem sucesso.

```
from tkinter import *

class Gui():
    """Classe que define a interface gráfica da aplicação
    """
    x_pad = 5
    y_pad = 3
    width_entry = 30


    #Criando a janela...
    window          = Tk()
    window.wm_title("Cadastro de Clientes")


    #Criando variáveis que armazenarão o texto inserido pelo usuário...
    txtNome         = StringVar()
    txtSobrenome    = StringVar()
    txtEmail        = StringVar()
    txtCPF          = StringVar()


    #Criando os objetos que estarão na janela...
    lblnome        = Label(window, text="Nome")
    lblsobrenome   = Label(window, text="Sobrenome")
    lblemail       = Label(window, text="Email")
    lblcpf         = Label(window, text="CPF")
    entNome        = Entry(window, textvariable=txtNome, width=width_entry)
    entSobrenome   = Entry(window, textvariable=txtSobrenome, width=width_entry)
    entEmail       = Entry(window, textvariable=txtEmail, width=width_entry)
    entCPF         = Entry(window, textvariable=txtCPF, width=width_entry)
    listClientes   = Listbox(window, width=100)
    scrollClientes = Scrollbar(window)
    btnViewAll     = Button(window, text="Ver todos")
    btnBuscar      = Button(window, text="Buscar")
    btnInserir     = Button(window, text="Inserir")
    btnUpdate      = Button(window, text="Atualizar Selecionados")
    btnDel         = Button(window, text="Deletar Selecionados")
    btnClose       = Button(window, text="Fechar")


    #Associando os objetos a grid da janela...
    lblnome.grid(row=0,column=0)
    lblsobrenome.grid(row=1,column=0)
    lblemail.grid(row=2,column=0)
    lblcpf.grid(row=3, column=0)
    entNome.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=50, pady=50)
    entSobrenome.grid(row=1, column=1)
    entEmail.grid(row=2, column=1)
    entCPF.grid(row=3, column=1)
    listClientes.grid(row=0, column=2, rowspan=10)
    scrollClientes.grid(row=0, column=6, rowspan=10)
    btnViewAll.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2)
    btnBuscar.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2)
    btnInserir.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=2)
    btnUpdate.grid(row=7, column=0, columnspan=2)
    btnDel.grid(row=8, column=0, columnspan=2)
    btnClose.grid(row=9, column=0, columnspan=2)



    #Associando a Scrollbar com a Listbox...
    listClientes.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollClientes.set)
    scrollClientes.configure(command=listClientes.yview)


    #Adicionando um pouco de SWAG a interface...
    for child in window.winfo_children():
        widget_class = child.__class__.__name__
        if widget_class == "Button":
            child.grid_configure(sticky='WE', padx=x_pad, pady=y_pad)
        elif widget_class == "Listbox":
            child.grid_configure(padx=0, pady=0, sticky='NS')
        elif widget_class == "Scrollbar":
            child.grid_configure(padx=0, pady=0, sticky='NS')
        else:
            child.grid_configure(padx=x_pad, pady=y_pad, sticky='N')




    def run(self):
        Gui.window.mainloop()
```

Comment: A Listbox não suporta múltiplas colunas. Existe o módulo TkTreectrl para esse efeito.

Comment: Como o @tomasantunes disse, não é possível usar múltiplas colunas automaticamente dentro da Listbox, você poderia nos dar um exemplo do que você quer?